# Google Analytics Bounce Rate > 100%

Tags: google-analytics

Looking at the analytics for my site, I see a handful of pages that somehow have a 150%, 390% and even 4,900% bounce rate!!!

How can that be? How can a bounce rate go beyond 100%?

Comment: Maybe that's percentage changed since the last period?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. My analytics report was for a single day (August 25th, 2014).

Comment: Yea I'm curious if this means your bounce rate had increased 150% since August 24th.  Perhaps post a screen shot of exactly what you see, or ask Google for clarification.

Comment: OK. I'm afraid I can't post the data from my company. I did run a report (Behavior > Site Content > All Pages... Showing Pageviews vs Bounce Rate in chart) and compared 24-25 and the numbers don't change that drastically. It's almost a straight line from the 24th to the 25th.